# Why can't I get the `for` command work in my command line

Tags: windows, scripting, command-line-interface, batch

This could also be read "Why can't I get the `for` command work in my batch file."

When I try using the command:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('something cool') DO something else cool %%a %%b %%c
```

It doesn't work! I'm getting:

> %%a was unexpected at this time

Comment: I'm mainly asking this because I've been asked this several times.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for this is that you need a single % when you're doing this in the command prompt and a double %% when you're doing it from a batch file.

Example Command Line:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %a in ('something cool') DO something else cool %a %b %c
```

Example Batch File:

```
FOR /F "tokens=1-4 delims=/ " %%a in ('something cool') DO something else cool %%a %%b %%c
```